# Encryption and Decryption With Only Special characters

Tags: c#, encryption, character-encoding

i have to Encrypt and decrypt a String but with only Special characters
i dont want alphanumeric to be part of encryption

i have tried Rijndael Encryption and i am getting only aplphanumeric Output

how can i get Special Characters

is there any other Algorithm for special characters

> Tried TripleDes provider and same result , is there any algorithm for selecting only special characters while encrypting
>
> I have A product and before shipping the Product i generate the Serial Key which contains Information about license ,now when Client activates the Software i want to Encrypt the Machine name + Serial key + motherboard no to generate the Activation key,now when ever my client opens the software i will decrypt the Activate key and validate the serial key and also whether he is using any other machine which i will compare with machine id and mother board no,for that i need a encryption which contains only special characters if it is possible ,till now its not working

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer currently. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @NitinBourai, do refer to this http://www.dijksterhuis.org/encrypting-decrypting-string/

Comment: @Nitin Bourai
: you may think you've asked a simple question, but in reality it is a poorly asked question, with little detail as to what specfic problems you are facing.

Comment: What's a special character in this context? There are no special characters generally, only characters that are special in certain cases.

Comment: @Mitch i accept i have poorly asked this question but look at your comment again you commented on my profile not on my question

Comment: special characters means characters except a to z and A to Z and 0 to 9

Comment: @Mitch lets close this down as this place is not to discuss such things thanks

Comment: I hope you realise that by limiting the output of any encryption output to exclude ascii byte values, you're making your data easier to crack.

Comment: How is this not a real question? It's very clear what he's asking (at least in its current state). Don't close a question just because you don't think what someone is asking for is a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computers are digital. In other words, *all* of the data they manipulate, including cipher text output from encryption, are discrete numbers.

So, when you say that the output is alphanumeric, you are really talking about a transformation of the output, not the output itself. Just use a different transformation on the output. Common transformations are Base-64 and hexadecimal, but these don't meet your (rather strange) requirements; you'll probably have to make up your own.

For example, you could represent the cipher text with "+" and "-" characters, mapping these to zero and one bits. Of course that could make some really long character strings!

Alternatively, if you could identify 16 "special characters", you could map each to a 4-bit value, and use something that amounts to hexadecimal with special characters instead of digits and letters.

Can I ask why in the world you want to do this?

Comment: i know this is weird and everyone knows the life of programmer ,just following order and trying

Comment: you made my day man ,problem solved i used Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");,thanks

Comment: @NitinBourai That won't work reliably. ISO-8859-1 doesn't map a character to every value between 0-255. So, sometimes you will get extra '?' characters in your output, and when you try to decrypt, the plain text will be corrupted or decryption operation will fail. Also, you will get some alpha-numeric characters, which I thought you wanted to avoid. I know of no character encoding that maps *every* byte to a character. You need something like Base-64 or devise your own.

Comment: i am Getting some ? while encrypting a long text and when decrypting i am getting back my Message ,what can be the problem i can get can you please explain

Comment: Thanks erickson i am getting some aplhanumeric but they are very few in number so i can consider this encoding

Comment: Please anybody but Nitin Bourai, who does not listen anyway, do not use just the encoding to/from iso-8859-1 (AKA Wester-Latin, if I'm not mistaken) to map around alphabetical characters.

Answer (score 1):

Take the hex characters you get from a hex output, map them one-to-one with some "special" characters and then map back on decrypting.

I'll bet this isn't solving any real problem. Apart from [Solitaire](http://www.schneier.com/solitaire.html), there hasn't really been many modern encryption systems using characters rather than bytes since the end of WWII, we just use characters in rendering the output.

Certainly, mapping like this isn't going to add anything in the way of security, just cause problems in portability.

Answer (score 1):

AES/Rijndael outputs bytes that appear random; you will get all values from 0x00 to 0xFF.  I suspect that what is happening is that at some point the bytes are being converted to either hex characters or Base64 to allow for display.  If you don't want characters then leave your output as a byte array and don't convert it.

Conversion from bytes to hex characters, or Base64, has no effect on the security of the encryption.  It just allows the cyphertext to be transmitted over systems which are expecting character data.